# Example django session and angular cookie with django rest framework

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework, session-cookies

Is there any full example on how Django rest framework can send session key to angular to save as cookie ??

Has been struggling for days...

I am running django on port 8000 and in angular ngserve I override httpclient to change the base url from 4200 to 8000 . However , it doesnt get any session,cookie data in the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked with Django and AngularJS for sometime. What we did was as below:

**index.html**

```
{% load google_analytics %}
{% load seo %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- ur code -->
</head>
<script src="{% static "JS/external/angular.js" %}"></script>
<body ng-controller="SiteController">
  {{ my_meta.heading }}
  <div ng-init="init('{{ session_key }}','{{ some_other_params }}')">

   <!-- your site code here -->

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In your **views.py** file:

```
@csrf_protect
@requires_csrf_token
def index(request):
    if request.session.session_key is None:
        request.session['has_session'] = True
        request.session.modified = True
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'session_key': request.session.session_key,
                                           ..... params which are to be provided before index.html has been rendered ......
                                          }
                  , content_type="text/html")
```

The `SiteController` had `ng-init` which was executed as very 1st thing before any other controller and page was loaded. We had `ecommerce` site so, the user had to `login` and `logout` and we maintained their activity using session.

If you have some different scenario or you need more help then elaborate your question more.

Comment: It seems both are the codes on server side...   can you also share the code in angular side that capture the session ?       for the code in views.py .. how is this incorporated in the django generic view ?

Comment: @SteveCheung: No, both are not server side. One is the template file `index.html` where we are passing the `session` key as an argument to `ng-init` method. I have not shown the `script` tag where I am using `angular.js` file in index.html